# Discord.py | Как узнать ID роли человека написавшего комманду

Tags: discord, discord.py

В данном фрагменте кода мне нужно узнать, есть ли ID данной роли в списке ролей автора.
ID роли - *767450270888099910*

```
@bot.command()
async def report(ctx, player: discord.Member, *args):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if 767450270888099910 in author.roles:
        await ctx.send('Предателям не давали право открывать рот! Скажи спасибо что ты можешь остаться на сервере...')
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут, увы только циклом:

```
for i in author.roles:
    if i.id == ROLE_ID:
        ...
        break
```

Comment: Не обязательно циклом, можно просто получить саму роль, и потом проверить входит ли она в список ролей пользователя